# MCRYPT_BLOWFISHでの暗号化／復号化の結果が PHP4.4.4 と PHP5.3.3 で異なる

Tags: php

PHP4.4.4(mcrypt 2.2.x) 上で構築されたWEBシステムがあるのですが、
今現在それをPHP5.3.3(mcrypt 2.5.8)に移行しようと思っています。
下のようにmcrypt_ecb()関数を使って正しく "my_data" という文字に
復号化するプログラムがあります。

```
$my_data = "xfZ3ruQZ+Is=";  
   // "xfZ3ruQZ+Is="という文字はPHP4.4.4上で
   // base64_encode(mcrypt_ecb(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH,"my_key","my_data",MCRYPT_ENCRYPT)) 
   // で暗号化された文字列です。

$my_key = "my_key";
$my_data = base64_decode($my_data);
$c_data = mcrypt_ecb(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH,$my_key,$my_data,MCRYPT_DECRYPT);
echo $c_data;
```

上記のコードですがPHP5.3.3 (mcrypt 2.5.8)だと"Dz}｢ﾂ鞅"という全く異なる文字列となってしまいます。
いろいろ試してみるとPHP4.4.4上で暗号化された文字列がPHP5.3.3で復号できなくて困っております。
(実際は、暗号化された文字列はデータベースに格納されています。)

どうにかして、"xfZ3ruQZ+Is="　という暗号化された文字列をPHP5.3.3でも正しく"my_data"に復号する方法はありませんでしょうか？

mcrypt_ecb()が廃止される関数であることは承知しておりますが、レガシーシステムなのでそれは承知の上でこの関数を使っております。

実際の環境では、PHP4.4.4でmcrypt_ecb(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH,...)関数で暗号化された文字列がOracleデータベース上に格納されておりまして、これらのデータを新しいPHP5.3.3の環境で復号化したいのです。膨大なデータなので移行データを整備することは避けて既存のデータをそのまま復号化したいと考えています。

どなたかお助けください。

Comment: マルチポスト：[本家SO「Defference in mcrypt(Blowfish) between PHP4.4.4 and PHP5.3.3」](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40254285)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHPではなくmcryptのバージョンの違いによるものと思われます。

詳細はさておき、古いmcryptのBlowfish実装にはバグがあり、mcrypt 2.5 で実装が修正、もとい変更されたようです。今回の場合、旧環境が mcrypt 2.2.x 、新環境が mcrypt 2.5.8 とのことなので、古い実装で暗号化されたものを新しい実装で復号しようとして、おかしな結果になっています。

古い実装は blowfish-compat として今でも残っており、PHPからだと `MCRYPT_BLOWFISH` の代わりに `MCRYPT_BLOWFISH_COMPAT` を指定します。（[実行例](https://wandbox.fetus.jp/permlink/C9WYMjphNXcbPw27)）

- [PHP :: Bug #18267 :: mcrypt-blowfish data encrypted on one machine not decryptable on other machine](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=18267)
- [What's the difference between Blowfish and Blowfish-compat? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11422497/2818869)

なお `mcrypt_ecb()` が廃止予定という点については、[マニュアル](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.mcrypt-ecb.php)に記載がある通り、`mcrypt_encrypt()` `mcrypt_decrypt()` に変更すればよいかと思います。こちらの関数も PHP 4.0.2 以上であれば使えます。

```
// mcrypt_ecb(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH,$my_key,$my_data,MCRYPT_ENCRYPT);
mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $my_key, $my_data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);

// mcrypt_ecb(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH,$my_key,$my_data,MCRYPT_DECRYPT);
mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $my_key, $my_data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
```

Comment: ありがとうございました。MCRYPT_BLOWFISH_COMPATで行けました。置き換え関数の情報もありがとうございました。